# Unable to determine syntax problem with creation of stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, syntax, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create the following stored procedure (XAMPP > phpMyAdmin):

```
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS changeTurn;
        
        DELIMITER //
        
        create procedure changeTurn(in currentGameID bigint(20))
        begin
            declare turnHasBeenChanged tinyint(1) default 0
            
            select @targetPlayer := player_number from game_players where gameID = currentGameID and current_turn = 1

            set @targetPlayer = @targetPlayer + 1

            update game_players set current_turn = 0 where gameID = currentGameID and current_turn = 1

            while turnHasBeenChanged = 0 do
                case
                    when @targetPlayer > 4
                    then set @targetPlayer = 1
                end
                case
                    when (select forfeit_next_turn from game_players where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer) = 1
                    then
                    update game_players set forfeit_next_turn = 0 where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer
                    set @targetPlayer = @targetPlayer + 1
                    else
                    update game_players set current_turn = 1 where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer
                    set turnHasBeenChanged = 1
                end
            end while
        end
        
        end //
        DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following issue with or without the delimiter:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @targetPlayer := player_number from game_players where gameID = curren...' at line 5
```

Unfortunately, this is not very specific.

When piecing this procedure together, I made sure I was using the correct syntax for each piece. But now it's altogether, it's borked. Please can you give me some direction as to why this is going wrong?

I checked line 4 (declare turnHasBeenChanged tinyint(1) default 0) in case its syntax was causing the succeeding line to fail, and added a semi-colon to the end of it, and that broke it at that line, so it wasn't that.

I then verified the syntax of line 5 against https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch01s15.html and it seems to be correct...?

Comment: You're missing the `;` at the end of the previous line.

Comment: You're missing LOTS of `;` characters all through the procedure. You need `;` at the end of every statement.

Comment: @Barmar I had semi-colons in it before and it gave me the same error for those lines. E.g. if I add a semi-colon at the end of line 4, it breaks on line 4 with the same error.

Comment: You have to add them after EVERY statement. Otherwise you'll get that error for the next statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every comand has to ended by a `;`

Also case when should be reaplce by an IF THEN

And at the end you have a end to much

so following gives no error any more

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS changeTurn;
    
    DELIMITER //
    
    create procedure changeTurn(in currentGameID bigint(20))
    begin
        declare turnHasBeenChanged tinyint(1) default 0;
        
        select @targetPlayer := player_number from game_players where gameID = currentGameID and current_turn = 1;

        set @targetPlayer = @targetPlayer + 1;

        update game_players set current_turn = 0 where gameID = currentGameID and current_turn = 1;

        while turnHasBeenChanged = 0 do
            IF @targetPlayer > 4
                then set @targetPlayer = 1;
            end IF;
            IF ((select forfeit_next_turn from game_players where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer) = 1)
                then
                update game_players set forfeit_next_turn = 0 where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer;
                set @targetPlayer = @targetPlayer + 1;
                else
                update game_players set current_turn = 1 where gameID = currentGameID and player_number = @targetPlayer;
                set turnHasBeenChanged = 1;
            end IF;
        end while;
    
    end //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I added semi-colons to all the statements and it kept throwing up the same error at different lines (in the context of using cases).

Comment: chekc my code you have a lot of bugs but mine works fine

Comment: I appreciate your help and yes your code works but I'm trying to understand why it didn't work with cases. You say I had a lot of bugs but I addressed them by taking your advice and adding semi-colons at the end of all the commands and removing the superfluous 'end'. Those fixes didn't solve the issue. Since your fix involved swapping cases for if/then, presumably what we're saying is that cases cannot be used in stored procedures? Apologies if I sound ungrateful, I just want to increase my understanding of the nuances of MySQL. :)

Comment: flow control is with case only in Select statements  possible